# JSF RICHFACES (<h:head> Tag Library supports namespace: http://java.sun.com/jsf/html, but no tag was defined for name: head)

Tags: jsf, richfaces

m working on JSF for past 3 weeks and i got stuck with richfaces ,actually my demo application is working fine but when i integrated it in my project it gave me this error:-

**Tag Library supports namespace: http://java.sun.com/jsf/html, but no tag was defined for name: head**

**my lib contain:-**

commons-beanutils-1.8.3

commons-codec-1.3

commons-collections-3.2

commons-digester-1.8

commons-discovery-0.4

commons-logging-1.1.1

hibernate3

hibernate-commons-annotations-3.0.0.ga

hibernate-validator-3.0.0.ga

jsf-facelets-1.1.15.B1

myfaces-api-2.0.2

myfaces-impl-2.0.2

richfaces-api-3.3.3.Final (1)

richfaces-impl-3.3.3.Final

richfaces-ui-3.3.3.Final

i think two jars are contradicting....

any help is welcome 
thnx
:)

Comment: Post the answer for you own question and accept it so that others might be able to see it in future.

Comment: problem was when we add JSF library using Eclipse download option it adds every thing but later for richfaces u need FacesViewer which is in jsf-facelets-1.1.15.B1 so at the time of execution ur page will take jsf-facelets-1.1.15.B1 library which does not support jsf2.0 so the new tags won't work but rest will work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error message is typical for a JSP tag library. The `<h:head>` is new since JSF 2.0. This thus means that you were attempting to use a JSF 2.0 specific tag in a JSP file. However, JSP has been **deprecated** as view technology since JSF 2.0. There is *no support* for JSF 2.0 specific tags like `<h:head>`, `<h:body>`, `<f:ajax>`, etc for JSP files.

You should be using Facelets (XHTML) instead.

#### See also:

- [Migrating from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441713/migrating-from-jsf-1-2-to-jsf-2-0)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, whilst RichFaces 3.3.3 will work on JSF 2.0 after several hacks, it's strongly recommended to immediately start with RichFaces 4.x when it concerns a new JSF 2.x project.

Comment: m using xhtml only but problem was contradiction of 2 libraries. i got it solved thnx for the reply :)